# webview scrolled horizontally on samsung s4

Tags: android, webview

I design a page in android with `webview` and set it's `setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled` as false. but in some device such as Samsung s4 content of this page scrolled to left and right . what is the problem ?

Comment: Did you check the Android Orientation before?

Comment: before when? before   setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled ?

Comment: kindly paste your xml code here